# Display text inside the bar in react chart js bar chart

Tags: css, reactjs, charts, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to make the text appear inside the bar in the bar chart using react-chart-js2. However, I am not able to find the necessary props or object key inside the options props.

```
 <div class="bg-white p-2 round mt-2">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <h5 class="usrs">Users Ratio</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                          <span class="mr-2">
                            <b>Female</b>:{" "}
                            {userRatio && userRatio?.female?.total} (
                            {userRatio &&
                              userRatio?.female?.percentage + "%"}
                            )
                          </span>
                          <span>
                            <b>Male</b>:{" "}
                            {userRatio && userRatio?.male?.total} (
                            {userRatio && userRatio?.male?.percentage + "%"}
                            )
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="use-avr4">
                          <Bar
                            data={BarData}
                            options={{
                              plugins: {
                                legend: {
                                  // align: "start",
                                  // title: {

                                  // },
                                  position: "left",
                                },
                              },
                              maintainAspectRatio: false,
                              responsive: true,

                              scales: {
                                x: {
                                  display: false,
                                  categoryPercentage: 1.0,
                                  barPercentage: 1.0,
                                  grid: {
                                    display: false,
                                    drawBorder: false,
                                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                                    drawTicks: false,
                                  },
                                },
                                y: {
                                  display: false,
                                  categoryPercentage: 1.0,
                                  barPercentage: 1.0,
                                  grid: {
                                    display: false,
                                    drawBorder: false,
                                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                                    drawTicks: false,
                                  },
                                },
                              },
                            }}
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

This is the Bar chart where the BarData is the object which is:

```
const BarData = {
labels: ["Male", "Female"],
datasets: [
  {
    label: "Male",

    data: [userRatio?.male?.total],
    fill: false,
    backgroundColor: ["#28a745"],
    borderWidth: 2,
    //borderColor: window.chartColors[colorName],
    pointStyle: "none",
    pointRadius: 1,
    pointBorderColor: "#3366cc",
  },
  {
    label: "Female",

    data: [userRatio?.female?.total],
    fill: false,
    backgroundColor: ["#dc3545"],
    borderWidth: 2,
    //borderColor: window.chartColors[colorName],
    pointStyle: "none",
    pointRadius: 1,
    pointBorderColor: "#3366cc",
  },
],
};
```

Here the userRatio is an object from the api response which is as:

```
usersRatio: {male: {total: 18, percentage: "69.23"}, female: {total: 8, percentage: 
"30.77"}}
    female: {total: 8, percentage: "30.77"}
    percentage: "30.77"
    total: 8
    male: {total: 18, percentage: "69.23"}
    percentage: "69.23"
    total: 18
```

This is the actual image that I want to get. https://ibb.co/4t1KbhZ

This is what it looks like now. https://ibb.co/X2RBVm0

Since I don't have the x-axis and y-axis labels displayed and turned then to false in the scales I am not able to think how should I approach this. Shall I use display true in the a and y axis inside scales object in the option prop and show the label or shall I just make some changes in the CSS (I am pretty weak in CSS though) ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, Cris. Did you ever find a solution?